# join query error on two super tables of TDengine

Tags: sql, time-series, tdengine

I want to join query two super tables of TDengine database.

The super table's schema is here:
s1 (ts timestamp, v int) tags (t bindary(64))
s2 (ts timestamp, v int) tags (t bindary(64))

```
taos> select * from s1, s2 and s1.ts = s2.ts

DB error: invalid SQL: super table join requires tags column

taos> select * from s1, s2 and s1.ts = s2.ts where s1.tag = s2.tag and s1.ts = s2.ts

DB error: syntax error near "tag = s2.tag;"
```

Could someone help to point me how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

just tried your queries on latest version of TDengine database, your queries should be supported now

```
taos> use test;
Database changed.

taos> create table st1(ts timestamp, v int) tags(t1 binary(64));
Query OK, 0 of 0 row(s) in database (0.003373s)

taos> create table st2(ts timestamp, v int) tags(t1 binary(64));
Query OK, 0 of 0 row(s) in database (0.003044s)

taos> select * from st1,st2 where st1.ts = st2.ts;
Query OK, 0 row(s) in set (0.001480s)

taos> select * from st1,st2 where st1.ts = st2.ts and st1.t1 = st2.t1;
Query OK, 0 row(s) in set (0.000686s)

taos> select * from st1,st2 where st1.ts = st2.ts and st1.t1 = st2.t1 and st1.ts = st2.ts;
Query OK, 0 row(s) in set (0.000728s)
```